# AngularJS not intercepting direct requests from Address Bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm creating an AngularJS application that uses the JWT token for authentication. The token is being passed using the AngularJS interceptor as shown below.

```
'request': function(config)
        {
            if (store.get('jwt_token') != null)
            {
                config.headers['x-access-token'] = store.get('jwt_token');
            }
            else
            {
                config.headers['x-access-token'] = '';
            }

            return config;
        }
```

Whenever I'm accessing any **`/restricted`** pages, everything is working fine. The issue is when I'm going to the **`/restricted`** page by directly typing the URL in the address bar (or refreshing the page), the AngularJS gets circumvented, and hence, the Interceptors don't intercept the request, and the token is not passed.

I've been searching for a while, I found some solutions like responding with a piece of code that loads the AngularJS then makes a redirect from there. However, **I'm looking for a simpler/neater approach if possible as I might be missing something here**.

I can detect if the request came from AngularJS or not by checking for the **`x-access-token`** since I'm always passing it (empty value if user is not authenticated).

**Solution**

Alex's answer is pointing to the exact problem, thanks Alex.

I finally figured it out yesterday. The solution I went with was to make sure all the requests come from AngularJS, I have a list of the restricted pages, if any of them is requested, I'm calling a function to verify and validate the JWT token on server side, if it's valid, proceed, otherwise, go to login page. **The key thing is to ensure that ALL requests should go to the index.html to make sure AngularJS is handling the routing.**

This link helped me greatly to solve this issue.

http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/

Comment: I feel that the request is not being intercepted before sending it to the server. Try adding: `$http.defaults.headers.common.x-access-token = store.get('jwt_token');` in your app.js.

Comment: Can you also add how you angular sending to the restricted page. I wonder if it waits for a 401 or just simply redirects.

Comment: What is that `store`? If it is some cookie service, than all is fine, because cookies are sent with request headers. If it is some localStorage etc, then what suggets @RahatMahbub should be enough ..

Comment: angular does intercept an api call. intercepting/non-intercepting your request should actually have nothing to do with if user types the address directly, or the routing happens thru router. ngRouter & ngResource are two totally different things. The problem might be the way you are registering the interceptor, mostly your interceptor is not getting registered when user directly enters the url

Comment: Im not really sure but couldnt you just watch a Statechange, and if the toState is restricted you could redirect or do whatever you want? So if the state is valid and the token then you can pass else you redirect to login for example or error page

Comment: Can you explain how angular is being circumvented? Is there a server side restriction on /restricted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as if there's a confusion between Angular's router and server endpoints.

You are presumably triggering the $http configuration while navigating through the application, using URL's tracked by Angular's router (which works fine), whereas the `/restricted` URLs are *server* URLs.

Therefore, when you ask for anything `/restricted` outside of the Angular app (in the browser), it is sending the request straight to the server, and not via the Angular router or application.

Basically, you need to create routes in your Angular app that are within the `restricted` context, that when initialized, run the $http configuration. You should never be calling server end-points directly in the address bar, except for `index.html` (`/`).

I'd suggest having an Angular route called `/restricted-area` so that when a user hits it, it will always use the $http methods you have, by being a dedicated Angular route, calling the server's `/restricted` endpoint internally, via a controller.

Comment: That's the issue that I was going through, I finally figured it out yesterday. The solution I went with was to make sure all the requests come from AngularJS, I have a list of the restricted pages, if any of them is requested, I'm calling a function to verify and validate the JWT token on server side, if it's valid, proceed, otherwise, go to login page. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had asked the similar question 2 months ago. What I have understood is, normally before javascript frontend frameworks how the http request were served was:

- We type a url in address bar.
- The browser sends the request.
- The server gets the request.
- serves the necessary html, js and css files.
- browser renders it.

But as the recent shift to various javascript frontend frameworks and use of RESTful api.s has begun, the request needs to have authorization header. Thus in many of the single page web apps with javascript frameworks like angularjs,

- the initial request for '/' router is sent
- the server serves the web application to your browser
- all the further routing in the web application is done within your front end application, hence the "#" after your url.
- Requests are made by the application to fetch, update, delete or post from your application through angular js.

So when you make request from angular application. Your request is intercepted from angular application and intercepted by your interceptor. However when you enter the url from your address bar, the browser sends request directly to server, because at that point of the request, the browser has not loaded your angular web application.

What I suggest is you set html5mode to false and put a `#` before your route.

like `localhost/#/restricted` and do the routing from your route provider. When there is `#` before your route, the request for `/` goes to server, your application loads, and make some controller in `/restricted` from your application make http request to desired server end point. In this way the request is sent through your application and will be intercepted by your interceptor. The refresh and directly typing the address in address bar works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume if you access the page **/restricted** your Angular app will start up correctly and it is just a login problem.

If you don't have a token then you have to redirect to the login page. You could show the login as a **modal** overlay then you don't have to switch the page. The interceptor will monitor the response result for status 401. In that case the interceptor will show the login. After the successful login the interceptor will execute the origin request - with the **token**.

You can find a working example in the [angular app](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/security/interceptor.js)

Answer (score -2):

just pass this token in cookies, not in header.

Comment: There are good reasons to use header tokens instead of cookies, such as better cross domain compatibility

Comment: But there is simply no way to force client to add header if he just makes http request. Also cookies can be protected from javascript, where headers cant as far as I know.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Here's some literature on cookies vs jwt and why jwt is passed in the header: https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/