# upon refreshing of the browser, the URLs containing 'hypen' is not going through angular $routeProvider .when(), but directly requesting the server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, url, express, route-provider

I am using MEAN Stack, and jade for html templating for developing a project. Since I am using jade all the .when() of the $routeProvider goes through the server and then rendered. Things are absolutely fine until recently I added $httpProvider.interceptor for authenticating each request. Basically, I started using JWT token based authentication and before requesting anything to the server, in my interceptor I am attaching 'Authorization' header. And the first middleware for protected apis I am verifying the token present in the 'Authorization' header. If present then proceed, else send authorization error.

Now, as mentioned in the title of the question. I have a few URLs containing ***hypen(-)*** between two words just to increase the readability.

eg: `.when('/firstPart/secondPart1-secondPart2/thrirdPart', {
         templateUrl: '/path/to/file'
     })`

this url is working fine if user going through the normal flow of getting to this url. The problem arises when the user comes to this page and hits the browser's refresh button, as he gets an error **'Authorization header not set'**

I did a few research on what and why this is happening, I found the answer in 
[AngularJS not intercepting direct requests from Address Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988271/angularjs-not-intercepting-direct-requests-from-address-bar). According, to this answer and few other I understood that on refreshing browser makes a direct request to the server and doesn't go through angular routes, and thus, interceptor that is attaching the Authorization header to each request header is not getting called.

As, suggested by the same link, the workaround is that if auth verification fails make a call to `'/'`, I donnot wish to do that as the user has just refreshed the page and he has to ideally get back the same page as he was in before he pressed refreshed. I am stuck here on how to do this.

Also, there is another mind–boggling this is if, I **remove the `'hyphen'(-)`**, and make it one word i.e., `.when('/firstPart/secondPart1SecondPart2/thrirdPart', {
         templateUrl: '/path/to/file'
     })`
everything works as expected even when the user hits the refresh button. It is first going through the angular router and interceptor attaches the Authorization header and then goes to make a get request for that template.

Wondering, is there any problem in using hyphen in URLs? However, I do not wish to remove the hyphens as I have already used it in many places and also I feel its good to have `-` between two words that needs to be displayed together in the URL than making them camel cased.

S, finally I have two questions : 
1. How to load the same page as the user was in before he hit refresh, instead of redirecting him to `'/'` or `login url`.
2. The problem explained above, occurs only for hyphenated(-) URLs, what is the problem having `'-'` in the URL.

Comment: If you are using Angular why jade is Necessary --Just a .html is Cool enough with  2way data binding -- if You provide a more code on your config.angular i can reproduce

Comment: I figured out the issue and fixed it.

Comment: Can you share your solution?

Comment: @duderoot yes sure.The problem with my URLs was that APIs and the angular(client) URLs were same. The APIs required Authorization headers to be set. When the Authorization header was not set application was designed to redirect to `/` or `login` page.
So, I came up with the solution of prefix each templateURL in the angular routing with a string(eg: `render`), and catch all the GET methods starting with `render` on the server side.
`app.get('/render/*', function(req, res, next) {
       var path = req.originalUrl.split('/').slice(2).join('/');
       res.render('./app/' + path);
});`